# Unable to save product sku to django model using post_save signal

Tags: django, django-models

Hello i am trying to save product sku to django model but it doesnt save anything and fails silently

here is the models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand , related_name='products')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', verbose_name='categories', related_name='products' , default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    SKU = models.CharField(max_length=100 , blank=True ,  unique=True)

def product_post_save_receiver(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    if instance.SKU is None:
        var1 = instance.title[:3]
        var2 = instance.brand.title[:3]
        var3 = var1+var2
        instance.SKU = var3
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(product_post_save_receiver,sender=Product)
```

what can i do to solve the above problem

thanks in advance

Comment: I have vote to close, they are not relevant code: **you say model is not save but you don't post how do you save model**. How it fails? **silently?** You should post steps to reproduce error. Also, you have a `save` into a `post_save` that means it will be save at infinitum if va13 is none again.

Comment: is the `instance.SKU` none?

Comment: `blank=True ,  unique=True` <- bad combination.

Comment: what can i do instead/

Comment: i am trying to save sku after the product object is saved so the sku field goes blank....i guess its the right way@Sayse@danihp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def product_post_save_receiver(sender,instance,**kwargs):
if instance.SKU is None:
    var1 = instance.title[:3]
    var2 = instance.brand.title[:3]
    var3 = var1+var2
    instance.SKU = var3
    instance.save()
```